# get media_id from instagram shortcode - graph.facebook.com

Tags: reactjs, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, instagram-api

Migrating away from the instagram api and moving on to  graph.facebook.com https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/reference/media#reading

Is it possible to use an instagram shortcode for example `B8RzB0AAhOO`  https://www.instagram.com/p/B8RzB0AAhOO/ to return the  media_id ?

I'm trying to find a similar npm package as [instagram-id-to-url-segment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/instagram-id-to-url-segment) but it is outdated with the new api

Comment: Looks like you will either have to get media IDs by going via a specific user account first, or use hashtag search / mentions to get them. Getting details about just any arbitrary media item, based on only its URL identifier, does not seem to be possible any more.

Comment: @misorude does it mean it's impossible to get the media_id from the URL shortcode?